# Sikuli type method does not support foreign characters

Tags: java, input, sikuli

I am trying to provide some automatic testing in regards to key pressed events, however Sikulis type() method seemingly does not support typing something like a asterisk (*) which is a standard key on a da_DK keyboard (to the right of ø), and the paste() method does not trigger a key typed event.

Do any of you know of a way to change the keyboard used by Sikuli?

Answer (score -1):

There may be some more complex ways to do what you're asking. But what i found helpful is to check which keyboard option is on before the test starts and then let Sikuli automatically change that.

[image]